# Configure PHP project in Eclipse

Tags: php, eclipse

I have created a PHP project in eclipse. When I need to run the project, I need to select a specific file and run it. How can I define a default file to run whenever I select project and click run button?

Answer (score 0):

Under the Run Button Menu select *Run Configurations*. Then Select either PHP CLI Application or PHP Web Application. There you can specify which file to use when running your project. If you only have one run configuration enabled, then this is what will run when you press the run button.

You can read the *Executing PHP* section of this [article](http://www.tigerheron.com/article/2008/01/eclipse-and-php) for slightly more detail.